# Mongo Complex Aggregator Query

Tags: mongodb-query

**For each `uniobj.a` I want count of distinct `uniobj.b`'s value**. How do I write this query? Is it feasible to directly write an aggregator query or I should MapReduce it and then write the aggregate query. The collection is preety large.